# How to edit font color in some words from a Text Component in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I know that React Native has a tutorial for this problem in their documentation but my problem is quite different because the string im rendering inside a Text component is from a database and not hard coded.

I have this skillDescription string that is stored in my firebase database. I wanted to edit colors in some words unfortunately the result gave me pure string 
[pic here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMgeB.png)
. My question is how can i edit some of words from this data?

Note: I have many string stored in skillDescription so i cant just hard code style in my Text component

Comment: Thats not possible because the text is dynamically generated .

Comment: Does that mean i dont have choice but to make this text a plain white string?

Comment: You can but if only the text is hardcoded. Let say if you have hundreds  line of texts, how do want to check if a portion of text match your condition and styling it.

Answer (score 1):

there is a very easy way! just like this:

```
 <Text style={{ color: "black" }}>let's <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', color: "green" }}>help</Text> to eachother in <Text style={{color:"red"}}>science</Text> .</Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best you can do is to save the string as an HTML string and use https://github.com/archriss/react-native-render-html to render the HTML.

You can use classes and define them in your react-native code.

An example (htmlBody) is your html read from database:

```
<HTML 
    html = {htmlBody}
    tagsStyles = {{
       span:  {fontSize: 16}, 
       p:     {fontSize: 16, color: 'green'}
    }}
    classesStyles = {{
     'ql-size-large': {fontSize: largeSize, color:'red'},
     'ql-size-small': {fontSize: smallSize, color:'yellow'}
    }
}/>
```

Answer (score -1):

To add style to your React Native component you can use `style` attribute - documentation [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/style).

There are many different variants to add styles, let's take two simple ways:

1. Simple variant (as @Mahdi Eslami presented) with adding style properties straight into style attribute like that:

   `<Text style={{color: "red"}}>Lorem lipsum</Text>`
2. Variant with styles defined in separate variable, like that:

   ```
   const styles = StyleSheet.create({
     red: {
       color: 'red'
     }
   });
   <Text style={styles.red}>Lorem lipsum</Text>
   ```

Comment: I believe the op is asking how to change a word or two within a text block, not how to apply styles in general.